# How to replace null value of object into list without for expression

Tags: java, spring, lambda, collections, java-stream

How i can do this code with stream and lambda functions, in JAVA 8:

```
//Replace null values with "NO"
for (Product product:
             listProduct) {
            if(product.getIsBreakStock().equals(null)) product.setIsBreakStock("NO");
}
```

I try with replaceAll function tutorial and foreach(), but IDE throw me an error:

```
listProduct.forEach(p -> 
                p.getIsBreakStock().equals(null) ? p.setIsBreakStock("NO") : p);
```

> Required type:
> void
> Provided:
> Product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this will help

```
    listProduct.stream().filter(p -> p.getIsBreakStock() == null).peek(p ->  p.setIsBreakStock("NO") ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Now throw me the reverse error, on p.setIsBreakStock("NO"):
Required type: Object, Provided: void

Comment: @LuisNox improved

Comment: Thanks u so much!! I cant vote up arrow, but i accept the answer. I really dont know about peek() function.